# PDF files download instead of viewing in browser tab

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, pdf, xampp

I'm developing an internal only application for a closed network using xampp on a Windows 7 PC and I have found that for some reason any PDF file that is over 15MB in size will be forced to download instead of viewing it in a new browser tab. The original public location of the file works as intended and uses the same code between the two sites, which has me thinking this is a server side file size limitation in xampp since anything under 15MB opens up correctly.

The browser is Chrome and I have made sure the setting in chrome is set to open, not download, and all other browsers tested do the same exact thing and the link attribute for all the PDF files is set to, target="_blank".

Is there a special size limitation setting in the php.ini or one of the apache config files that needs to be added or edited?

Thank you!

Comment: RESOLVED: I found that it was in fact the application and not the server side. The application I am using is called Grav, a simple flat file CMS. There is a plugin called "External Links" and when that is installed it is apparently overriding something. Remove the plugin, everything works.